# Add column to existing powershell output

Tags: sql, powershell

[image]

Please help me on below scenario.

```
$emp = $Result | select name,employer | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I have created a function `aghealth()` which gives some value.

How can I add the value of `aghealth` to `$emp`.

Comment: What kind of object is `$Result`? `$Result | Get-Member` will tell you. To clarify: are you after a new column which has multiple values? How do these values relate to the exisintg name and employer in `$Result`

Comment: @gms0ulman,i added the output values for.Please let me know if more info needed

Comment: Typename :System.Data.Datarow

Comment: What does the function do? How is it called? Does it just output a list of values? How do you correlate those values with the records in `$Result`?

Comment: Yes function just pulls list of values.I want to insert those values to already existing powershell output.

Comment: $Result + AGHealth is what I need to see.

Comment: Please post more code so that we can understand how the data is generated. I am attempting a response based on what you have provided but can't verify this will work.

Comment: Again, how do you correlate the function output to the records in `$Result`?

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially loop over the values in `$Results` and add the AGHealth values. If this function takes one of the `$Results` values as input, that's great. Otherwise you can use indexing into the array (assuming it returns an array...)

```
$i = 0
foreach($Result in $Results){

    [array]$actualResults += New-Object psobject -Property @{

        "Name"      = $Result.Name
        "Employer"  = $Result.Employer

        # I don't know which of these is most suitable as no idea how aghealth works
        # This will not work with duplicates so 2 of these have to go.
        "AGHealth"  = aghealth($Result.Name)
        "AGHealth"  = aghealth($Result.Employer)
        "AGHealth"  = $someVariableThatAlreadyHasAGHealthResults[$i]

    }

    $i++
}

$actualResults | Format-Table
```